# Thinking out of Prolog and into Haskell - Generating Lists of Truth-Value Combinations

Tags: haskell, prolog, combinations, list-comprehension, translate

I know a bit of a Prolog and have just started some self-study in Haskell. I have been working through the [99 Problems for Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/H-99%3a_Ninety-Nine_Haskell_Problems), learning much along the way and really enjoying Haskell. Sometimes I try to clarify my understanding of a problem space by coding something in Prolog and then thinking how that solution might relate to a functional approach in Haskell. Tonight, while working on the problems about logic (problems 47 and 48), I got distracted trying to accomplish the simple task of building up a list of the lists of all truth-value combinations with n values. I want a function `tValues :: Int -> [[Bool]]`.  This problem can be solved in a very straightforward and declarative way in Prolog, e.g.:

```
combinations_of_n_truth_values(N, AllValues) :-
    findall(Values, n_truth_values(N, Values), AllValues).

n_truth_values(N, TruthValues) :-
    length(TruthValues, N),
    maplist(truth_value, TruthValues).

truth_value(true).
truth_value(false).
```

When used, the variable `AllValues` will unify with the desired list of lists of truth-values. I would like to know how an experienced Haskell programmer would go about solving this same problem. I would expect there is an equally straightforward and declarative solution, but I can't seem to get my Haskell brain functioning in the right way.

I have fiddled with some semi-analogs using list comprehensions, such as the following:

```
tValues:: Int -> [[Bool]]
tValues 0 = []
tValues n = [v:vs | v  <- tValue
                  , vs <- tValues (n-1) ] 

tValue :: [Bool]
tValue = [True, False]
```

but `tValues` only returns `[]`. I think I just need some human-to-human engagement to help shake my head clear and maybe grace me with a deeper insight.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In pseudo-code, your list comprehension

```
[v:vs | v  <- tValue
      , vs <- tValues (n-1) ]
```

equals

```
for any combination of two elements in `tValue`  and `tValues (n-1)`
    cons the first onto the latter
```

However, `tValues` has no elements to begin with, it is an empty list. Lets simulate this for `n = 1`:

```
tValues 1 = [v:vs | v  <- tValue
                  , vs <- tValues 0 ] 
          = [v:vs | v  <- [True, False]
                  , vs <- [] ] 
            -- since there is no vs
          = []
```

This propagates throughout the whole recursion. The solution is quite simple: change the base case to contain an empty combination:

```
tValues 0 = [[]] -- or: return []
```

Now the simulation yields:

```
tValues 1 = [v:vs | v  <- tValue
                  , vs <- tValues 0 ] 
          = [v:vs | v  <- [True, False]
                  , vs <- [[]]] 
            -- vs is []
          = [True:[],False:[]]
          = [[True],[False]]
```

Which is just what we wanted.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I think this clarifies several problems I was having when trying to work with list comprehensions. It is also encouraging to learn that I was overlooking a minor detail, rather than fundamentally misconceiving the issue. I also appreciate the natural language translation, as my studies in Prolog have habituated me to formulating answers in simple declarative statements and constructing algorithms on this basis.

Comment: Would you be interested in weighing in on the relation between this approach and the others offered here? E.g., is there an ideological difference motivating the explicit use of the list monad as opposed to sticking with the list-builder syntax, or is it a mere matter of style/convenience? Regardless, thanks again!

Comment: @aBathologist: I still call myself a Haskell beginner, so my point of view is probably not really a professional one. For me, it's more or less a matter of convenience: the list comprehension syntax is easy to read and can be understood by Haskell beginners. It can even be translated to a monadic form immediately: `do { v <- [True, False]; vs <- tValues (n-1); return (v:vs);}` (predicates can be done via `guard` from `Control.Monad`). This intermediate monadic version can help you to find such elegant ones as m09's `flip replicateM [True, False]`. At the end it's up to you.

Answer (score 6):

With the list monad,

```
g n = mapM (\_-> [True, False]) [1..n]
```

About your function's base case. As the function returns a list containing *all truth-values lists of length `n`*, it follows that for `n=0` it should return a list containing *all truth-values lists of length 0*, i.e. a list containing one empty list.

Comment: very nice indeed, better than my version, +1 :)

Comment: and to explicit the part that "uses the monad", we could write it `sequence . replicate n $ [True, False]`

Comment: Delving even deeper into the monadic library functions, your `sequence . replicate n` already exists as `Control.Monad.replicateM n`.

Comment: so `replicateM n [True, False]` certainly wins the shortness contest!

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and for helping rectify my erroneous base case. I will need to do a bit of reading on the list monad to understand how `mapM` combines the number list and the lambda to generate permutations, and I appreciate the spur to further study. Cheers.

Comment: actually, this is exactly the translation of *your* Prolog code, `maplist(truth_value, N_long_list)`, because Haskell's list monad expresses nondeterminism by collecting a list of all solutions for a predicate, as if by an implicit `findall`. So it's exactly the same code, map for map. :) and you're welcome. :)

Comment: and the numbers in the numbers list are of course ignored by the lambda function with the wild card argument, `(\_ -> ...)`. `[1..n]` is just "a list of length `n`". --- as to how it works, i.e. [its translation into basic `(>>=)`-using code](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:mapM), it's equivalent to  `g 0 = return []; g n = [True, False] >>= (\x-> g (n-1) >>= (\xs-> return (x:xs)))`, very close to the initial code in m09's answer, and exactly equivalent to your list comprehension code actually.

Comment: These explanations are *very* helpful! (With this explicit translation from Prolog add in, your answer ought to be the most "accept"-worthy, but I feel silly shuffling the "award" around, since it's the inessential thing.) Your explanation also helps me appreciate monads as more than just a convoluted notation to accommodate imperative constructs: they seem to facilitate the encapsulation of alternative computational strategies? Many, many thanks for these insightful elucidations.

Comment: "alternative computational strategies" is exactly how monads are usually viewed: list type `[]` for nondeterminism, `Maybe` for possibility of failure, `Either` allows failure to carry its own information, etc.

Answer (score 4):

```
truths :: [[Bool]]
truths = [True] : [False] : concatMap (\bs -> [True:bs, False:bs]) truths

truthValues :: Int -> [[Bool]]
truthValues n = dropWhile ((< n) . length) . takeWhile ((<= n) . length) $ truths
```

`truths` is an infinite list of all truth value combos, because the lengths increase monotonically we can just take the front part of the list while the lengths are less than or equal to the sets we're looking for, then drop the front of that whose lengths are less.

The reason you are only getting the empty list back is that eventually `tValues (n-1)` evaluates to `tValues 0` which is of course the empty list. Trying to draw from the empty list in a list comprehension causes that iteration to fail. This propagates up the chain of comprehensions. Change the base case to `tValues 1 = [[True], [False]]` and it will work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your interesting solution and for giving such an understandable diagnoses of the problem with my base condition. The other answers didn't point out the fact that `v <- []` is a failing condition, and understanding this really helps clarify the issue for me. I really like this approach, which generates an abstract object consisting of all possible series of truth values. I do balk a bit at the overhead of having slice the desired sets out of the middle of the infinite list though. But this might be more a psychological issue than a computational one? Many thanks!

Comment: Glad you found value in it! You're correct though, this is definitely not the most efficient solution that has been given here. It's mostly a clever novelty using the same pattern as my favorite definition of the Fibonacci sequence, `fibs = 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)`

Answer (score 4):

Not a complete answer per se, but if it interests you, with the list monad:

```
truthValues ∷ Int → [[Bool]]
truthValues 0 = return []
truthValues n = truthValues (n - 1) >>= (\l → [True:l, False:l])
```

or

```
truthValues n = foldM (\l _ -> [True:l, False:l]) [] [1..n]
```

or

```
truthValues = flip replicateM [True, False]
```

See also Will Ness' answer and the comments attached :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers. My afternoon plan revolves around studying your solutions to understand clearly what's going on. Your list-monad answers do indeed interest me: I would be particularly interested in hearing a bit about the motivation for working with the list monad directly as opposed to just using the list-builder syntax. Are there particular use-cases which lead you one way or the other, or is it more a matter of principle?

Comment: Judging superficially, it looks to like working with the monad leads to a more imperative style what with the binding and `return` and `flip` etc.). Is this a common feature of working directly with monads, or am I perhaps misreading here? Many thanks!

Comment: `return` is not imperative in nature. It's not the same thing as return in an imperative language: it just puts the value it's given into the monad. Here `return []` could have been written `[[]]` as well. `flip` was just used here to achieve a point-free style, we could have written `truthValues n = replicateM n [True, False]`
instead. Here what is nice about the list monad is that its core --- its `bind` operation --- does precisely what you want: ie it combines two values in a non-deterministic fashion (a la Prolog). That's why the last solution is so short and to the point.

Comment: yes, `replicateM n [True,False]` practically says in English, "`n` non-deterministic Boolean values". very nice indeed. :) --- about `return`, better name could've been `inject` - or *`yield`* even.